# Property not being returned from database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: references (top) and tweets (bottom):

```
tweet_id  class_id
------------------
2         1
5         1
6         2

tweet_id  text
------------------
1         foo
2         bar
3         baz
4         foobar
5         boobaz
6         foo bar
7         bar baz
```

I want to retrieve all info of tweets that are in the references table. The desired output is:

```
tweet_id  class_id  text
---------------------------
2         1         foo
5         1         foobaz
6         2         foo bar
```

I'm now using:

```
SELECT r.tweet_id, t.text, r.class_id
FROM tweets t 
LEFT JOIN `references` r ON (r.tweet_id = t.tweet_id) 
ORDER BY r.tweet_id ASC LIMIT 100
```

But this leaves me empty-handed when trying to fetch the tweet_id. The text, however, is displayed:

```
while($tweet = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  echo "$tweet->tweet_id $tweet->text"
}
```

In the resultset (checked via phpmyadmin), tweet_id and class_id for each record is NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind :-) I should have `LEFT JOIN`'ed vice versa:

```
SELECT r.tweet_id, r.class_id, t.text
FROM `references` r
LEFT JOIN tweets t ON (r.tweet_id = t.tweet_id) 
ORDER BY r.tweet_id ASC LIMIT 100
```